# Real Time Reporting API with demographics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

i am developing a new project where I need to get demographics stats like gender and age group from each one visitor who just arrives to a webpage. I cannot find any documentation from Google about Real Time Reporting API giving demographics.
I would like to ask you if this is possible to be done ? Is there any way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demographics data is not included in the Real Time API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/. Please also not that Real time reporting API is in beta.

At the moment all you can do is access the demographics via the Core Reporting API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=audience.