# real time demographic data for website personalization

Tags: analytics, personalization, bigdata

How to get basic demograpic Data for personalizing a webpage.

There is [quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/) but it doesn't provide this functionality.
To personalize a webpage it is necessary to get this information in real time, to adapt the webpage before sending it to the visitor.

It's called website personalization and there are alot blog entries about how to gather this data, but there is not one how to use existing data.

Is there a solution ready to use?

Comment: similar question: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Does-anyone-offer-real-time-website-visitor-demographics-data-as-a-service

Comment: 2 year old Question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193873/real-time-reporting-api-with-demographics

Comment: other Question: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Reports/Real-Time-User-Demographics/td-p/746493#